# scrollTop() is not scrolling to the correct place on IE windows 8 phone

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mobile, windows-mobile

It's working fine everywhere, although the browser returns the right height, it scrolls to the wrong position(different one each time) this only happens on IE W8 phone, here is the code:

```
$("#navigation-wrapper a").click(function(e){
    $headerHeight = $("#header").height();
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - $headerHeight});
e.preventDefault(); });
```

Any idea?

Comment: I've just noticed this too.  For me it's bouncing as well, when it shouldn't, so I'm assuming it's a jQuery bug.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is messy, but for some reason it worked. I had to call animate twice in order to scroll to the right place.

```
$('html, body').stop()
  .animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - $headerSize},function(){
      $('html, body').stop()
        .animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - $headerSize});
    });
```